# First order logic PROVERs in NLTK: how to solve?

Tags: python, nlp, logic, nltk, solver

In NLTK there are [3 PROVERs](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html): Prover9, ResolutionProver and TableauProver. Typically they can prove a goal, saying True or False at the end. Then if we want to know all the 'x' satisfying an expression, for e.g. all the *mortal(x)* I know only one way to do it, with ANSWER:

```
import nltk.inference
rexp = nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring
p1 = rexp('man(socrates)')
p2 = rexp('all x.(man(x) -> mortal(x))')
p3  = rexp('mortal(x) -> ANSWER(x)')
tp = nltk.ResolutionProverCommand(None, [p1,p2,p3])
if list(tp.find_answers()): 
   for ans in list(tp.find_answers()): print(ans,end=' ')
else: print('No answer')
```

But this ANSWER has many limitations: it sends a 'set' so identical answers disappear; you cannot get x and y for e.g. brother_of(x,y); sometimes it gives answer when there is no ([other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666291/python-nltk-resolutionprover-finds-a-solution-when-in-fact-there-is-no))

Question: how to solve x, y, etc of such first order logic expressions? With ResolutionProver, or Prover9 or TableauProver despite these two don't even have an ANSWER possibility...

Any comment on the 'best' FirstOrderLogic solver among the above 3 or beyond (non-toy) is welcome: PyLog, FLiP, Pythologic, Karen, pyDatalog, other? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No answer? Python nor NLTK would have no solver? As a temporary solution I will use PySwip in order to connect to SWI-PROLOG where the solver engine is very powerful, but I'd prefer to have a full-Python solution, thx guys!