# Python NLTK ResolutionProver finds a solution when in fact there is no

Tags: python, nltk, resolution, solver, inference

I have this rule of format *"if A&B then C":*  if *b is_man* and *s is sister_of b,* then *b is brother_of s*

I add the fact that *is_man(luc)* and I request if there is any 'b' for *brother_of(b,leia)*

I expect the answer to be negative because it is not said that leia is sister_of luc, so in my rule *"if A&B then C"* the B part is not true, but ResolutionProver surprisingly answers 'luc' ??!?

```
import nltk.inference
rexp = nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring
p1 = rexp('is_man(luc)')
p2 = rexp('(is_man(b) & sister_of(s,b)) -> brother_of(b,s)')
answer = rexp('brother_of(b,leia) -> ANSWER(b)')
tp = nltk.ResolutionProverCommand(None, [p1,p2,answer])
if list(tp.find_answers()): 
    for ans in list(tp.find_answers()): print(ans,end=' ')
else: print('No answer')
```

It should not answer Luc but False, how can I get False ? And get 'luc' only in case I'd declare in addition sister_of(leia,luc). Thank you !

PS: for info, here is the proof:

```
[1] {is_man(luc)}                                                  A  (that is p1)
[2] {-is_man(z368), -sister_of(z369,z368), brother_of(z368,z369)}  A  (that is p2)
[3] {-brother_of(z370,leia), ANSWER(z370)}                         A  (that is answer)
[4] {-sister_of(z369,luc), brother_of(luc,z369)}                   (1, 2)  (combination of 1 & 2)
[5] {ANSWER(z370), -is_man(z370), -sister_of(leia,z370)}           (2, 3) 
[6] {-sister_of(leia,luc), ANSWER(luc)}                            (1, 5) 
[7] {-sister_of(leia,luc), ANSWER(luc)}                            (3, 4)
```

Comment: When trying the example code, python returns `NameError: name 'rexp' is not defined`.  How to include `rexp`?

Comment: Hi Slagel, I've added 2 lines at the top of the code for rexp. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have commented this issue on:
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3046

The problem is that the function `find_answers()` in the `ResolutionProverCommand` class in `nltk.sem.logic` checks for ANSWER() but does not check that the empty clause is derived.